# Gradle sync issue Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, adt

I am Newbie to android,
When i build by gradle files It shows error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.animalfacechanger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
}
android { sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/res/assets'] } } }
android { sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/color'] } } }
```

Comment: Try to go to Build - Rebuild project.

Comment: your project location in C directory?

Comment: set `compileSdkVersion 23` & set `targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: or you can only set `buildToolsVersion "22.0.2"`

Comment: Stil its of no use @IntelliJAmiya I have tried it.

Comment: For testing case you can comment V4 library

Comment: Thank you I will check ..!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help ...!! Finally  solved it...!!!

Comment: @PreethamHegde Check my answer .

Answer (score 4):

I understand this question is old, however, for the sake of people like myself who came/will come across this question while facing the same problems, I decided to provide the solution that worked for me.
From Gradle 3.4, you need Java 8 and above.
Add this to your app level `build.gradle` file

```
...

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
}

 ...
```

Clean your project and run app.

Answer (score 2):

For your **`mergeDebugResources`** problem .

At first Comment `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'`
and Use `buildToolsVersion "22.0.2"` .

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.application.animalfacechanger"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

Then **Build -Clean- Rebuild project** . I hope it will helps you .